# 2010 decennial variables vs. 2020 decennial variable in Tidycensus

Tags: tidy, census

I'm trying to analyze sex by age in the 2020 census data, but when I used

`load_variables(2020, 'pl', catch = FALSE)`

I couldn't find any related variables. Additionally, when I checked the number of observations in the resulting table, there were only 301, which seems too low. This is strange, since the 2010 decennial data had up to 27,850 variables. But when I load the variables using

`load_variables(2020, 'pl', catch = FALSE)`

It says 'API endpoint not found. Does this data set exist for the specified year?"

However the variable code not working if I change the year to '2010'.

How to obtain the sex by age variables for the 2020 census data?